# Rabbitmq Message Publishing Retry

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ. If, for any reason my publisher cannot send the message, I would like to retry to send the message again. How can I keep on retrying to publish the message until it reaches to message broker.

Is there any way in which I can approach this? Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
try {
       channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
       $queueMsg = new AMQPMessage($Body, array('delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT););
       $channel->basic_publish($queueMsg, '', $queue);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log ("Failed to send message");
        /*HERE I WANT TO RETRY SENDING MESSAGE BY CALLING basic_publish() method again!! */

    }
```

Comment: there is some logic to retry message with adding middle queues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270322/how-in-rabbitmq-and-php-return-task-back-to-the-queue

Comment: Hi @Spring, Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I keep on retrying to publish the message until it reaches to message broker

Re-trying a publish operation is specific to the programming language you are using. Since you don't provide your code, I can just give general hints - check return values from RabbitMQ, handle exceptions correctly, and re-try in cases where the publish did not succeed.